# Malformed line in checkpoint file [/var/lib/kafka/data/log-start-offset-checkpoint]

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have a kafka cluster run with docker compose. At the first run everything is working fine but when I close my windows machine and reopen it and start docker cluster again kafka container fails. I tried a few times to create cluster after deleting it but no luck. Can anyone help me, please? Here kafka container's logs.

```
2023-06-10 18:27:46 java.io.IOException: Malformed line in checkpoint file [/var/lib/kafka/data/log-start-offset-checkpoint]: 
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at org.apache.kafka.server.common.CheckpointFile$CheckpointReadBuffer.buildMalformedLineException(CheckpointFile.java:172)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at org.apache.kafka.server.common.CheckpointFile$CheckpointReadBuffer.toInt(CheckpointFile.java:167)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at org.apache.kafka.server.common.CheckpointFile$CheckpointReadBuffer.read(CheckpointFile.java:133)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at org.apache.kafka.server.common.CheckpointFile.read(CheckpointFile.java:106)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at kafka.server.checkpoints.CheckpointFileWithFailureHandler.read(CheckpointFileWithFailureHandler.scala:48)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at kafka.server.checkpoints.OffsetCheckpointFile.read(OffsetCheckpointFile.scala:70)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$loadLogs$4(LogManager.scala:384)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:563)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:561)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:926)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at kafka.log.LogManager.loadLogs(LogManager.scala:353)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at kafka.log.LogManager.startupWithConfigOverrides(LogManager.scala:522)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at kafka.log.LogManager.startup(LogManager.scala:482)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:263)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
2023-06-10 18:27:46     at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
2023-06-10 18:27:46 [2023-06-10 15:27:46,150] WARN Error occurred while reading log-start-offset-checkpoint file of directory /var/lib/kafka/data, resetting to the base offset of the first segment (kafka.log.LogManager)
2023-06-10 18:27:46 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Error while reading checkpoint file /var/lib/kafka/data/log-start-offset-checkpoint
```

And this is my docker compose file.

```
version: "2.1"
name: kafka-cluster-single
services:
  zoo1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    hostname: zoo1
    container_name: zoo1
    networks:
      - my-network
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888;zoo2:2888:3888;zoo3:2888:3888
    volumes:
      - ~docker/volumes/kafka-cluster-single/zoo1/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ~docker/volumes/kafka-cluster-single/zoo1/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log

  zoo2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    hostname: zoo2
    container_name: zoo2
    networks:
      - my-network
    ports:
      - "2182:2182"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2182
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888;zoo2:2888:3888;zoo3:2888:3888
    volumes:
      - ~docker/volumes/kafka-cluster-single/zoo2/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ~docker/volumes/kafka-cluster-single/zoo2/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log

  zoo3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    hostname: zoo3
    container_name: zoo3
    networks:
      - my-network
    ports:
      - "2183:2183"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2183
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888;zoo2:2888:3888;zoo3:2888:3888
    volumes:
      - ~docker/volumes/kafka-cluster-single/zoo3/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ~docker/volumes/kafka-cluster-single/zoo3/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    hostname: kafka1
    container_name: kafka1
    networks:
      - my-network
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092,DOCKER://host.docker.internal:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181,zoo2:2182,zoo3:2183"
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: "true"
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: "30"
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    volumes:
      - ~docker/volumes/kafka-cluster-single/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest
    networks:
      - my-network
    depends_on:
      - zoo3
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka1:19092"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "default"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_statuses
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schemaregistry:8081"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schemaregistry:8081"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "localhost"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars
    volumes:
      - ~docker/volumes/kafka-cluster-single/kafka-connect/jars:/etc/kafka-connect/jars
      - ~docker/volumes/kafka-cluster-single/kafka-connect/etc/kafka:/etc/kafka

  kowl:
    image: quay.io/cloudhut/kowl:master
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
    networks:
      - my-network
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERS: kafka1:29092
      CONNECT_ENABLED: "true"
      CONNECT_CLUSTERS_NAME: "my-connect-cluster"
      CONNECT_CLUSTERS_URL: http://connect:8083/
      SCHEMAREGISTRY_ENABLED: "true"
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - ~docker/volumes/kafka-cluster-single/kowl/etc/configs:/etc/kowl/configs
      - ~docker/volumes/kafka-cluster-single/kowl/etc/secrets:/etc/kowl/secrets
networks:
  my-network:
    external: true
```

Comment: Try upgrading to 7.4 release tag? Also not really clear why you need 3 Zookeepers

Answer (score 0):

> when I close my windows machine and reopen it

Sounds like you're not running `docker compose stop`, and therefore the server processes running in the container do not have time to properly shut themselves down, meaning flush any open file handles and finish any writes.

So, yes, it's possible that corruption could happen. This isn't unique to Docker